# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int nf(t)\cos(tn)e^{-n|t|}dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Find
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\mathbb{R} nf(t)\cos(tn)e^{-n|t|}dt
$$
assuming that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, bounded and integrable.

I know that before putting limit inside integral we need to do some substitution inside. But honestly, I do not know what substituion and why. So any hint would be gratly appreciated.

Maybe we could use substituion $t=u/n$, then $dt=du/n$ and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\mathbb{R} nf(t)\cos(tn)e^{-n|t|}dt=2\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\infty} nf(t)\cos(tn)e^{-nt}dt=2\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\infty} f(u/n)\cos(u)e^{-u}du=2\int_0^{\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty} f(u/n)\cos(u)e^{-u}du=2\cdot f(0)\int_0^{\infty}\cos(u)e^{-u}du=f(0)
$$
But I am not sure if it is what we are looking for.

Comment: The very first "=" does not hold true since $f$ does not need to be symmetric. You have to consider $\int_0^{\infty}$ and $\int_{-\infty}^0$ separately.

Comment: @saz, you're right